# How to specify if the input to be in a custom interval

Tags: c

I got this homework :P (still new in c)
Teacher asked us to ask the user to type a variable X and must be between [10 .. 20] or [100 200]
in pascal we used to do X in [10 .. 20] but this time in C it doesn't work . Any suggestion to specify an interval ? i don't want to keep limiting the x if it's above 20 or less than 10 etc etc
My work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int x;
printf("Donner Un X\n");
do {
    scanf("%d",&x);
} while (x in [10 20]) || (x in [100 200])  ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x in [10 20]` is not C syntax. It should be `10 <= x && x <= 20`

Comment: loop must exit if the read value is within the bound, then condition check must be `while (!((x > = 10 && x<= 20]) || (x>=100 && x<=200)))`

Comment: I'm aware for that im already if in C are there any similars to x in [10 .. 20 ] It's pain to type  (10 <= x && x <= 20) || (100 <= x && x <= 200)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Never use `scanf` without cheching return value. Your variable `x` is not intialized and will contain indetermined value when first calling `scanf`. If the user enters some letter instead of a number, `x` is not updated and when you use it, you cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: What shall i use instead of Scanf @Gerhardh

Comment: I didn't tell you not to use it. But you should check the return value. Check the [manpage for `scanf`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-de-dev/scanf.3.de.html) for return type and expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of comparition operators (`<=`, for example) and logical and operator `&&` to check if the value is in the intervals.

Also you want the variables to be in the intervals, so retrying should be only when the value entered is *out of* the intervals.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("Donner Un X\n");
    do {
        scanf("%d",&x);
    } while (!((10 <=x && x <= 20) || (100 <= x && x <= 200))); /* retry if x is NOT in any of the intervals */
    return 0;
}
```